# How to use div to split screen in bottom and top section where bottom is fixed height and top takes remaining space

Tags: html, css

How do I split my HTML page into two rows using divs, where the bottom div has a height of 100px and the top div takes up the remaining space.

Currently I have the following, however here the top div overlaps the bottom div:

```css
html,
body,
object {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
div {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#mainContainer {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#topContainer {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#bottomContainer {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="topContainer">
      This is the top div
    </div>
    <div id="bottomContainer">
      This is the bottom div
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I have tried using display: table; which works fine in Chrome and Firefox but unfortunately not in IE9 (which is a requirement). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change `#topContainer` to

```
#topContainer {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 100px;                //set bottom
  height: calc(100% - 100);     //calculate height
  width: 100%;
}
```

Rest of your code works well.

Here is updated snippet.

```css
html,
body,
object {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
div {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#mainContainer {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#topContainer {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 100px;
  height: calc(100% - 100);
  width: 100%;
}
#bottomContainer {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="topContainer">
      This is the top div
    </div>
    <div id="bottomContainer">
      This is the bottom div
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @ShrinivasShukla isn't the solution affecting the width of the topcontainer?

Comment: Why would it affect the `width`? It is still `100%` as it was before.

Comment: @ShrinivasShukla that's what i got when i applied the solution.. Just wanting to learn..

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the above method that friends say

you can use `display: table;` it's never top div overlap the bottom div

for show `display: table;` in IE9 you can use

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

html & css:

```css
html,
body,
object {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
div {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#mainContainer {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#top{
  display: table-row;
}
#topContainer {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid red;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#bottom{
  display: table-row;
}
#bottomContainer {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  bottom: 100px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="top">
      <div id="topContainer">
        This is the top div
      </div>
      </div>
    <div id="bottom">
      <div id="bottomContainer">
        This is the bottom div
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As mentioned in my original question, I have tried to use the display: table; option. Unfortunately this won't work well with IE9 which is a requirement for us.

Comment: i edit answer for solves this problem in IE9 test it

Comment: Thank you Sadegh, this also does the trick! Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this html markup:

```
<div class="top">
   This is your top div
</div>
<div class="bottom">
  This is your bottom div
</div>
```

And the matching styles:

```
.bottom {
    position: fixed; 
    bottom: 0px; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100px; 
    /*  Added styles for demo */
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

Here it is injsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b59y4f1s/1/

Comment: The problem with this solution is that eventually the top div will overlap the bottom div. I really need to have the top div take all the remaining space that is left after the bottom div

Comment: No, the bottom will overlap the top. And it actually will make *top div take all the remaining space that is left after the bottom div*.

Comment: I guess you meant, *top div take **only** the remaining space that is left after the bottom div. Anyway, I'm glad you got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
html,
body,
object {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
div {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#mainContainer {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#topContainer {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 86.1%; // exact percentage
  width: 100%;
}
#bottomContainer {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
<body>
  <div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="topContainer">
      This is the top div
    </div>
    <div id="bottomContainer">
      This is the bottom div
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```