# Splitting the screen with 2 dividers

Tags: html, css

A SO member asked a question about dividing the screen with 2 dividers, having the bottom divider take a fixed height, and the top divider taking the rest of the height.

This was his code"

```
 html,
    body,
    object {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
    div {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
    #mainContainer {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    #topContainer {
      border: 1px solid red;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    #bottomContainer {
      border: 1px solid blue;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100%;
    }
    <body>
      <div id="mainContainer">
        <div id="topContainer">
          This is the top div
        </div>
        <div id="bottomContainer">
          This is the bottom div
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

My solution was to give the topcontainer, a height of  86.1%

Is my solution considered wrong? and why?

Comment: Seems like you are referring to this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692041/how-to-use-div-to-split-screen-in-bottom-and-top-section-where-bottom-is-fixed-h

If the `#topContainer` takes `86.1%` of height, then the `#bottomContainer` will get `13.9%` height., which is **NOT FIXED**.

Comment: @ShrinivasShukla what is exactly wrong with my answer, what are its consequences?

Comment: @dan -- the question-asker asked for the bottom container's height to always be 100px tall. Your code will set the bottom container's height to be 13.9%. 13.9% is not the same thing as 100px. The problem with your answer is that it simply does not do what the original question-asker requested.

Comment: On a device with screen height = `1000px`, the `#bottomContainer` will be `139px` in height. On a device with screen height = `500px`, the `#bottomContainer` will be `69.5px` in height. If the height is **changing** on different devices, then it is **NOT FIXED**, which is NOT according to the requirement.

Comment: @ShrinivasShukla thank you very much for explaining that, i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

As I see it, your solution will set the topContainer's height to 86,1% of its parents height. If you resize your screen the topContainer's height will shrink/grow as well. Therefore it will not always match the bottomContainer's edge.

Look at Shrinivas answer in the original post, the bottomContainer already has a fixed height of 100px that you can work with and the CSS function `calc()` can calculate a height - and the best thing is, you can add and subtract pixels from percentages and the other way around. Therefore setting the topContainer's height to `calc(100% - 100);` will make it full height minus the fixed height of the bottomContainer. This solution will work with every screen and window resolution.

Answer (score 1):

i have not much repu to comment thats why i am putting the comment here

i run it in JSFIDDLE and i am sure that you solution is correct.

```
#topContainer {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#bottomContainer {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

try it by yourself here

[JSFIDDLE Demo Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/xqdv1gzw/10/)